# Query from a BigQuery database via a Google Cloud Function (Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a big Query Database connected to a Google Sheet in which I have a read only access
My request is that I want to get data from a table and this request is working perfectly fine in the Big Query editor but I want to create a Google Cloud function to have an API and access this request directly from URL
I have ceated a Service Account using this command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create connect-to-bigquery
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding test-24s --member="serviceAccount:connect-to-bigquery@test-24s.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/owner"
```

and I have created a Google cloud function as follow :
[Creating Cloud Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZGI7.png)

[Service account settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcxRh.png)

Here is my code for main.py file :

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
def hello_world(request):
 client = bigquery.Client()
 query = "SELECT order_id, MAX(status) AS last_status FROM `test-24s.Dataset.Order_Status` GROUP BY order_id"
 query_job = client.query(query)
 print("The query data:")
 for row in query_job:
   print("name={}, count ={}".format(row[0], row["last_status"]))
 return f'The query run successfully'
```

And for the requirements.txt file :

```
# Function dependencies, for example:
# package>=version

google-cloud-bigquery
```

The function deploys successfully however when I try to test it I get this error :

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Details:
500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

And when reading the log file I found this error

```
403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.
```

Please help me to solve this I already tried all the solutions that I found on the net without any success

Answer (score 0):

Based on this: "Permission denied while getting Drive credentials" - I would say that your service account's IAM permissions are not 'transient' => while that service account probably has relevant access to the BigQuery, it does not have access to the underlined spreadsheet maintained on the Drive...

I would try - either

1. extend the **scope** of the service account's credentials (if possible, but that may not be very straightforward). Here is an article by Zaar Hai with some details - [Google Auth — Dispelling the Magic](https://blog.doit-intl.com/google-auth-dispelling-the-magic-d3c114d39eef) and a comment from [Guillaume](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere) - ["Yes, my experience isn't the same"](https://guillaume-blaquiere.medium.com/yes-my-experience-isnt-the-same-63ac3c783864);

or (preferably from my point of view)

2. make a copy (may be with regular updates) of the original spreadsheet based table as a native BigQuery table, and use the later in your cloud function. A side effect of this approach - a significant performance improvement (and cost savings).

Comment: Can you tell me how to configure my account's credentials ? I have tried to see the google documentations but I still get the same error

Comment: I've added a link to a Medium article, where Zaar described the 'scope' a bit...